# How can I properly annotate a Sequelize model with flow-typed?

Tags: sequelize.js, flowtype, flow-typed

I'm using `flow-typed` with `sequelize^4.44.3`. It's complaining because the `Model` has no parameters. But that seems to be the standard way to create models with Sequelize, so what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with `sequelize` but with regards to Flow, you'll need to supply some type parameter to `Model` like `Model<{}>` or `Model<Object>`, although both of those are not entirely type-safe. Take a look at https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/sequelize_v4.x.x/flow_v0.104.x-/test_sequelize.js for examples on using the `Model` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's [take a look at the libdef](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/sequelize_v4.x.x/flow_v0.42.x-v0.103.x/sequelize_v4.x.x.js#L3076-L3081).

As you can see, the `Model` class is defined as:

```
class Model<TAttributes, TInitAttributes = TAttributes, TPlainAttributes = TAttributes>
```

There are three type parameters here, the second two of which are optional because the default to the first. So let's break them down one-by-one:

### TAttributes

This is an object type that represents the attributes of your model class. I can see in your screenshot that you have a string field called `name`. Let's assume for the sake of example that you also have a count of participants in your `Conversation`. So your `TAttributes` for a model with just those two fields might look like this:

```
type ConversationAttributes = {
  name: string,
  participants: number,
};
```

Now we can take this type which defines our attributes and pass it into the `Model` class as a type parameter to define our model:

```
class Conversation extends Model<ConversationAttributes> {
  // ...
```

This should work fine, but we have some other options as well:

### TInitAttributes

This defaults to `TAttributes`, so in our example it will be `ConversationAttributes`, so we don't need to specify it in this case.

`TInitAttributes` is the type used for construction of a new record. If this type is different from `TAttributes` for some reason, you can specify it here (probably in the case of some computed property that would exist on `TAttributes` but would make no sense on `TInitAttributes`.

### TPlainAttributes

This defaults to `TAttributes`, so in our example it will be `ConversationAttributes`, so we don't need to specify it in this case.

`TPlainAttributes` is the return type of the `toJSON` method and it's also the return type of the `get` method when passing `{plain: true}` as the options. If the "plain" serialization of our attributes differs from `TAttributes` in some way, we could specify the type of the "plain" version here.